# Can I cascade 2 HP MSA60 enclosures and create a RAID1+0 array over all disks

Tags: hp, hp-proliant, hp-smart-array, storage

I have a DL380 G5 (p411 SmartArray Controller) with a single loaded MSA60 (12x2TB SATA)and am purchasing a 2nd to cascaded as illustrated above. If I do this with identical disks (another 12x2TB SATA) can I apply RAID1+0 across the disks between the 2 enclosures for better I/O & resiliency?

Comment: I don't see any illustration...

Answer (score 1):

Yes. You can create a single logical drive that spans multiple [StorageWorks MSA60 enclosures](http://h18000.www1.hp.com/products/quickspecs/12627_div/12627_div.HTML) with the [Smart Array P411](http://h18004.www1.hp.com/products/quickspecs/13202_na/13202_na.html) controller you're planning to use.

If I/O performance is the key, you may not see tremendous gains. The MSA60 is capable of dual-domain configuration (MPIO), but it's also a 3G SAS unit (versus a 6G SAS). Also, you're using SATA drives, which will probably negotiate at 1.5Gbps. Resiliency may not be a big concern, as the [MSA enclosures are well-built](https://serverfault.com/questions/461973/why-are-enterprise-sas-disk-enclosures-seemingly-so-expensive/461977#461977). If you RAID 1+0, you'll want to pair drives across enclosures, or perhaps skip the cascading and run the enclosures off of separate ports on the P411 controller.