# High density disk bay rack chassis - why such a big difference in price?

Tags: storage, sas, rack, hardware

We're looking for a chassis with 45-60 bays for SAS/SATA disks and we found some 60-bay enclosures at ~ $11000 (see [here](http://www.dataonstorage.com/dataon-products/6g-sas-jbod/dns-1660-4u-60-bay-6g-35inch-sassata-jbod.html) and [here](http://www.rackmountnet.com/bay-ultra-density-jbod-dual-redundant-module-and-1200w-power-supply-p-5541.html) for example - there are others as well).

However we found [this one](http://www.supermicro.com/products/chassis/4u/847/sc847e16-rjbod1.cfm) which have 45 bays (or 36 bays as server chassis) for $1700.

We think that the price difference is way too big (the price/bay is more than triple). Why is this?

I do NOT ask why the SAS enclosures are so expensive but why are so **big differences between the prices of the SAS enclosures of different kinds**. I think that's a different question from [this one](https://serverfault.com/questions/461973/why-are-enterprise-sas-disk-enclosures-seemingly-so-expensive).

Comment: Feel free to join ServerFault's [chat room](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/127/the-comms-room) where there will be a couple of people interested in your requirements.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> We think that the price difference is way too big (the price/bay is more than triple). Why is this?

The price difference is a function of the capabilities of the product. As @TomTom said, multiple paths, zoning, power supplies, and hot-swap components are all features of a [high-end JBOD storage enclosure](https://serverfault.com/questions/461973/why-are-enterprise-sas-disk-enclosures-seemingly-so-expensive/461977#461977).

Now, I would suggest that building a server today with a large amount of local storage requires some research and understanding of the implications of that design.

*Can you elaborate a bit on why you need 45-60 disks in one enclosure?*

Is this for storage capacity? IOPS requirements/performance? Do you need 2.5" disks or 3.5" disks?

There was a time when it made sense to do something like this... especially if there was some form of replication or application-level resiliency. This was when servers like the [Sun x4540](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H1cEQ.jpg) were popular. But if this is a standalone server, I'd go with a head unit (2U server) and cascade one or more JBOD enclosures via SAS to arrive at the required capacity. More modular, safer design, less risk of the entire setup dying. [The disks should probably be SAS as well...](https://serverfault.com/questions/331499/how-can-a-single-disk-in-a-hardware-sata-raid-10-array-bring-the-entire-array-to/331504#331504) but that's another discussion.

Comment: *"Can you elaborate a bit on why you need 45-60 disks in one enclosure?"* - backup. We need to backup 100+ TB. No much need for speed, but we must be sure that we will NOT lose data.

Comment: @JohnThomas If you're looking to spend that much on storage, you need to look at pre-built products like ExaGrid.

Answer (score 3):

Look at the features and it becomes clearer.

The cheaper one from SuperMicro is a flat "extend a server" element.Redundant power supplies but "that is it". Simple SAS expander.

The other ones are part for a SAS network inrastructure. Multiple controllers (hot swappable), zoning support - the idea is not that you ahve 60 bays for a server but 60 bays and can split them between multiple servers.

Naturally - if you do not need the features, the cost is "OMG" high.